# Why can a static class variable not be allocated to the stack?

Tags: c++, static, heap-memory, stack-memory

Normally, a local variable declared in a function is allocated on the stack, not on the heap, but this is not the case if the variable is static. Why can a static class variable not be allocated on 
the stack?

Comment: The use of the term "stack" in this question, and in some of the answers provided, is entertaining, if not presumptive. The standard defines what you're referring to as "automatic" variables, or automatic storage. In fact the only usage in the standard for "stack" is the `<stack>` standard library container and reference to function-call behavior in exception conditions and destructor firings, referred to as "stack unwinding" (15.2). It is honestly not the right term for your question, or the answers.

Comment: @WhozCraig As it happens I didn't use the word 'stack' in my own answer, but I don't care for the patronizing tone of this comment, and speaking as a compiler writer I find the content a mere quibble.

Comment: @EJP It wasn't meant for your care, not approval. It was meant to bring to light that the very concept of automatic storage per the standard is not reduced to the all-too-common assumption of a "stack". Its entirely up the implementation, and as a compiler-engineer for the better part of 23 years, I've been party to several implementations that *don't* use the traditional model. You're certainly free to consider it a mere quibble, but neither myself, nor the standards committees, consider it so, and we're all entitled to our opinions. (and +1 on your answer, both brief, and inarguable).

Comment: Technically you could put them on the stack if it was before the entry to main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime of a local static variable is the whole of the program, but the stack is used, reused and reused again over multiple function calls, by all functions. Therefore static local variables can't be stored on the stack together with the other local variables.

Answer (score 3):

Because then it wouldn't be static. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2):

Variables allocated on the stack are automatically deleted. You don't want a static variable to be deleted.